# How to understand "And Scabbers was here first, and he's ill!" in this context

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 'Crookshanks doesn't understand it's wrong!' said Hermione, her voice shaking. 'All cats chase rats, Ron!'
>
> 'There's something funny about that animal!' said Ron, who was trying
>   to persuade a frantically wiggling Scabbers back into his pocket.
>   'It heard me say that Scabbers was in my bag!'
>
> 'Oh, what rubbish,' said Hermione impatiently. 'Crookshanks could
>   smell him, Ron, how else d'you think —'
>
> 'That cat's got it in for Scabbers!' said Ron, ignoring the people
>   around him, who were starting to giggle. '**And Scabbers was here first,
>   and he's ill!**'
>
> Ron marched through the common room and out of sight up the stairs to
>   the boys' dormitories.

I don't quite understand what point Ron was trying to make by "*And Scabbers was here first, and he's ill!*". It seems to me that it's not relevant to the context at all. The context looks pretty straightforward, but I don't understand the logic behind it. How should we understand it in the context?

-- From Harry Potter - and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ron is looking for reasons that Crookshanks the cat should not chase Scabbers the rat. Hermione says it’s a fact of nature. Ron points out that his rat is ill, the implication being that the healthy cat shouldn’t chase the ill rat.

The phrase "I was here first" is often used to indicate that "I" am the eldest. It’s also used when queuing to show precedence. Scabbers is almost as old as Ron, which is old for a rat. He is, presumably, older than Crookshanks and should take precedence in the pecking order. Ron, as second youngest in his family, is probably often told to respect his elders. Chasing or trying to eat your elders is not respectful.

Ron believes that Crookshanks is not just following instinct by hunting a rodent, but it has a particular murderous intent to kill his pet rat. He also believes that Crookshanks was able to understand human speech and understood when Ron said that Scabbers was in the bag. "... got it in for ..." means "wants to murder". Here Ron is acting paranoid, and Hermione calls it "rubbish". Cats hunt rats and mice naturally and why would the cat particularly want to hunt that one rat(!?)

Comment: I don't think it is the presumed age of the rat or the cat.  Ron is saying that he has had his pet for longer than Hermione has had hers. So if one of the pets has to go (to avoid conflict) then it should be Crookshanks, not Scabbers. However Ron is behaving rather irrationally here.

Comment: @JamesK ok, But How do you interpret "'That cat's got it in for Scabbers!'" then? Is it referring that that cat got in this school only for Scabbers or what?

Comment: @JamesK Or maybe another interpretation could be: Scabbers came to Hogwarts school first/earlier than the cat, if one should be gone to avoid the conflict, it should be the cat. Does it sound reasonable?

Comment: @JamesK Another thing confused me is: what 'it' refers to In "That cat's got it in...". What do you think?

Comment: @JamesK has a good interpretation there. Crookshanks came to Hogwarts with Hermione, but Scabbers came with Fred and George who are a year (?) older. So, yes, last in, first out. The cat should go. "Having it in for someone" is an idiom, similar to "doing someone in", and there was a hot network question on that recently, I think.

Comment: @pam I've edited to answer the questions in the comments.  Feel free to adopt or reject this edit if you don't feel it matches your intent.